# cannot declare objects inside an object of a Class in javascript

Tags: javascript, class

```
class A{
    obj = {};
    obj.x = 0;
}

let a = new A()
```

Why we cannot do this(create an object inside a class and give it a property) inside a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define instance fields with that syntax (outside of the constructor), but not mutate them. Don't confuse the `=` syntax with the usual assignment syntax, as it really has different rules. For instance you can also use this syntax:

```
class A {
    ["obj"] = {};
}
```

If you want to mutate fields/properties, you'll have to do this inside the constructor or other method. On the other hand, nothing stops you to initialise the field with a more elaborate object literal.

NB: to create an instance you should use the `new` keyword.

So either do:

```js
class A {
    obj = { x: 0 };
}

let a = new A();
console.log(a.obj.x);
```

Or do:

```js
class A {
    obj = {};
    constructor() {
        this.obj.x = 0;
    }
}

let a = new A();
console.log(a.obj.x);
```